# Make doxygen document enums like Qt

Tags: qt, enums, doxygen

Is there a way to make doxygen output for enums look like Qt's documentation of their enums?
Compare: [Doxygen enum](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/examples/enum/html/class_enum___test.htm) vs [Qt enum](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WindowState-enum).

As you can see, doxygen (apart from having no taste) doesn't show the numerical value of the enum at all, which is useful for or-combinable flags. I've made the doxygen output look a bit better by forcing the enum constant and description on the same line by tweaking the CSS, but I haven't found a way to fix doxygen for the numerical value.

I'm aware I could make the whole table manually by inserting HTML code into the enum documentation, but that's a lot of unnecessary duplication of information.

Answer (score 2):

Qt uses [**qdoc**](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/index.html) to document it's sources. I don't think you can mimic it's output using the traditional doxygen tool.

By the way, [qdoc is deprecated and they recommend using doxygen instead](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/HEAD/tools/qdoc3/README.TXT).